# tcpip() command implementation in Octave

Tags: matlab, tcp, octave

Is there an implementation of the tcpip() command from the Instrument Control Toolbox from Matlab? I've searched for it but with no luck until now.

Documentation for the tcpip() command on Matlab is here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/instrument/tcpip.html

I want to use the same syntax to make my Matlab-Scripts 100% compatible with Octave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has not been implemented in Octave yet. There is a [sockets package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/sockets/index.html) which can be used for it but its API is not matlab compatible. There is also a new Octave package for [instruments control](http://andriussutassocis2012.blogspot.de/2012/09/progress-report.html) but it doesn't have those functions yet. The [proposed plan](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dFpxKwtr3IZQ-XrLjgqSot4rR-BTPzscCqJ2Fe0g-T8/edit?pli=1) is to indeed implement them (see the SocketCAN support for Linux platform section) but they are at the end of it. Maybe you could help Andrius on implementing them?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew the sockets package and it would be suitable if developing in Octave, but the plan was to run Matlab-developed scripts in Octave.